# changing Host in Header randomly for nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to make a reserve proxy by nginx for accessing to many servers form one website and one URL.
for example I need to make one site by nginx by this URL:
**www.main.com**

which is redirecting via its server to many other sites:

**www.server1.com**

**www.server2.com**

**www.server3.com**

**...**

which these servers are some times busy so I need to refusing for redirecting to those busy servers and redirect instead to free servers.

SO by randomly or by some variable similar to time_out to responsible and ...

So i knw about proxy_pass and i made one similar site for this works by this code:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
error_log {{OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}}/app-root/logs/nginx_error.log debug;

pid        {{NGINX_DIR}}/logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    #access_log $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/access.log main;
    port_in_redirect off;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  0;
    #keepalive_timeout  165;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/javascript text/javascript text/css;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_http_version 1.1;

    upstream frontends {
        #server pr4ss.tk;
        #server 222.66.115.233:80 weight=1;
        server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:8081 ;

    }
    upstream frontends2 {
        server google.com;
        #server 222.66.115.233:80 weight=1;
        #server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:8081 ;

    }
    upstream index0 {

        server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15001 weight=1;
        server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15002 weight=2;
        server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15003 weight=3;

    }
    upstream index {
        #server vb-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
        #server vb.elasa.ir;
        #server  vb-elasa3.rhcloud.com ;
        #server vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
        #server forums.fishsmarket.tk;
        #server  community.elasa.ir;
        #server free-papers.elasa.ir;
        #server  diy4tornado-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com weight=1;
        server diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
        server diy2-elasa2.rhcloud.com backup;
    }
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one2:10m rate=1r/m;
    limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=one3:10m rate=1r/m;
    proxy_cache_path  /tmp  levels=1:2    keys_zone=RUBYGEMS:10m  inactive=24h  max_size=1g;

    server {
        listen      {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:{{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT}};
        server_name  {{OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}} www.{{OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}};
        root {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};


        set_real_ip_from {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}};
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /main {
            root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        }
        location ~* ^/(.*) {
            #root   html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;



            proxy_set_header Host  diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
            #proxy_set_header Host  $upstream_addr;
            proxy_pass_header Server;
            #proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
            #proxy_redirect  http://vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com/ http://community.elasa.ir/;
            #proxy_redirect  http://fm.elasa.ir/ http://community.elasa.ir/;
            proxy_pass http://index/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            #sub_filter 'href="http://fm.elasa.ir/'  'href="http://community.elasa.ir/';
            #sub_filter '<base href="http://fm.elasa.ir/'   '<base href="http://community.elasa.ir/';
            sub_filter 'http://fm.elasa.ir/'   'http://community.elasa.ir/';
            sub_filter_once on;

        proxy_set_header X-outside-url $scheme://$host;
                    #proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;





        proxy_cache            RUBYGEMS;
        proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                               http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


            client_max_body_size 100M;
            client_body_buffer_size 1m;
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_buffer_size 128k;
            proxy_buffers 256 16k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            #proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
        }

        location ^~ /admincp {
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/admincp/(.*)$ /index.php?routestring=admincp/$1 last;
                }
                proxy_set_header Host vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
            proxy_redirect  http://vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com/ http://diy-elasa2.rhcloud.com/;
            proxy_pass http://comment/$1$is_args$args;
        }
        location /www {
            #root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
        location /categories {
            #root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends2;
        }
        location /index0 {
            #root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;
            # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
            #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;


            # enable this if you forward HTTPS traffic to unicorn,
            # this helps Rack set the proper URL scheme for doing redirects:
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
            # can be set properly within the Rack application
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
            # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
            proxy_redirect off;

            # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
            # Comet/long-poll/streaming.  It's also safe to set if you're using
            # only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx, but not slow
            # clients.  You normally want nginx to buffer responses to slow
            # clients, even with Rails 3.1 streaming because otherwise a slow
            # client can become a bottleneck of Unicorn.
            #
            # The Rack application may also set "X-Accel-Buffering (yes|no)"
            # in the response headers do disable/enable buffering on a
            # per-response basis.
            # proxy_buffering off;






            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      10;
            proxy_send_timeout         5;
            proxy_read_timeout         3600;

            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 132k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    264k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 164k;
            proxy_pass http://index;            


            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }




        location ~ \.php$ {

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?routestring=$1 break;
        }

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
#fastcgi_param HTTPS on;

fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
#fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

}
        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}
         location ~ \.php1$ {
                # handles legacy scripts
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?routestring=$1 break;
                }

                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_pass   {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
                fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
                fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
                fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
                fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

it's working but only redirect to first site from two list site:

upstream index {

```
    server diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
    server diy2-elasa2.rhcloud.com backup;
}
```

and the site only redirect to **diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com** which is added to:

```
location ~* ^/(.*) {
            #root   html;
            #index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_set_header Host  diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
```

as **proxy_set_header Host** .

So how could I reach to my goal?

Answer (score 0):

i added:

```
 upstream main {
    server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15010 weight=1 fail_timeout=1s;
    server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15011 weight=1 fail_timeout=1s;
    #server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15012 weight=1 fail_timeout=1s;
    keepalive 300;

    }

server {
  listen      {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15010;
  server_name diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
  location ~* ^/(.*) {
    proxy_pass       http://diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
    proxy_set_header Host diy-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com;
    }
    }

    server {
  listen      {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15011;
  server_name diy2-elasa2.rhcloud.com;
  location ~* ^/(.*) {
    proxy_pass       http://diy2-elasa2.rhcloud.com;
    proxy_set_header Host diy2-elasa2.rhcloud.com;
    }
    }
    server {
  listen      {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:15012;
  server_name diy-phantomjs4so.rhcloud.com;
  location ~* ^/(.*) {
    proxy_pass       http://diy-phantomjs4so.rhcloud.com;
    proxy_set_header Host diy-phantomjs4so.rhcloud.com;
    }
    }
```

and finally:

```
server {
        listen      {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:{{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT}};
        server_name  {{OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}} www.{{OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}};
        root {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};


        set_real_ip_from {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}};
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /main0 {
            root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        }
        location  ~* ^/(.*) {
         proxy_pass http://main;
        }
 }
}
```